# Spring JPA save update in certain order

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Code snippet in my spring service

**to update the existing record**

```
      //Credit Cards
      find.getCreditCards().forEach(creditCard -> {
        creditCard.setActiveVersion(false);
        businessPartnerCreditCardRepository.save(creditCard);
      });
```

**And then insert new 1**

```
//Credit Cards
      businessPartner.getCreditCards().forEach(creditCard -> {
        creditCard.setVersion(find.getVersion() + 1);
        creditCard.setActiveVersion(true);
        businessPartnerCreditCardRepository.save(creditCard);
      });
```

The issue is that , Spring JPA first run the **INSERT** statement and then **UPDATE**, instead of first run the **UPDATE** then **INSERT**.

**why I need certain order from UPDATE to INSERT**

There is a DB constraint that only 1 record is active at a time. so, when JPA insert without update .. DB shout and kickback to ..... :D

Any Update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a flush after the update.

You can use [`saveAndFlush` from the JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAndFlush-S-) or write a custom method in your repository where get the EntityManager injected and perform the flush on it.

Another option would be to make the constraint a deferred constraint so it is only checked at the end of the transaction.